# Patern maching like Select Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that contains this kind a structure of a column, how can I make select only from character 4 to 6 to ignore other character that are outside this boundary , I tried `LIKE'%544%'`, `RegExp`. ect.  ??

```
1   000544001

2   000054400

3   000544010

4   000344010

5   000544011
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use `substr()`:

```
where substr(col, 4, 3) = '544'
```

another is to use `like`:

```
where col like '___544%'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use mid(col,start,length) statement

like  this

```
select column1 from table1 where mid(column1,4,3);
```